# Unity, perspective axis in a 3d world

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems

In a world of geometry, the X axis represents left to right, Y axis up and down and Z axis adds perspective. Basically you would look down Z axis onto X-Y plane. From this [**LINK**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)
"*For three-dimensional systems, a convention is to portray the x–y plane horizontally, with the z axis added to represent height (positive up). Furthermore, there is a convention to orient the x-axis toward the viewer, biased either to the right or left*"

So why does Unity treat Y as the "up" axis? that is a perspective axis, right? Seems to be the trend in the gaming world, but not from the math perspective.

I realize that in a 3d world perspective is not absolute, but what is the reason to look down the Y axis? Shouldn't 3d world be consistent with 2d world and keep X Y working coordinates with Z being a perspective axis?

The only possible answer I got from wiki: "*However, computer graphics and image processing often use a coordinate system with the y axis oriented downwards on the computer display. This convention developed in the 1960s (or earlier) from the way that images were originally stored in display buffers.*". However, I don't understand this answer, it seems too weak to break the standard and flip everything around.

Appreciate any insight.

**EDIT:** The reason i am asking is I am developing a 3d game with a friend of mine and we need to decide which axis to use as a perspective axis. Per geometry, we should use Z axis looking down onto X Y plane.Per unity and alot (most?) of gaming standards we should use Y axis looking down X Z plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Z (or "forward") is the perspective axis in Unity. For better understanding you can switch to 2D mode in scene view. You'll be left with X and Y axis, with X pointing to the right and Y pointing up as you look on the screen. In it's turn Z axis will face forward (codirectional to your look direction), so Z really will be perspective/depth/forward axis.

Comment: I don't believe so, when you create a new 3d project, the camera looks down onto X Z plane, so its looking down the Y axis, not Z one. I don't have access to unity atm, but I believe that is the case.

Comment: No, it isn't. I've just created a new project to verify that and it looks like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9niw736guzrs5z/unity_z.png 
So the camera is shooting "forward", codirectional to blue Z axis, thus looking onto XY plane.

Comment: You are right, I just verified this. I guess I got confused by the whole top-down perspective, depending what the view is, you look at different planes.